# update rich:datatable when rich:inputNumberSlider value change

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf, richdatatable, rendered-attribute

my interface is like in the picture

[image]

I want the value of the réduction field changes when the value of the inputNumberSlider changes.

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider id="slider"
    rendered="#{bean.showReductionForm}"
    value="#{bean.reduction}" 
    showArrows="true" 
    width="220"/>
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="datatableId"
    ajaxSingle="true"
    actionListener="#{bean.appRed}" />
```

any help plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `a4j:support` as a child of `rich:inputNumberSlider` in order to make it work.

Also for performance and usability reasons I would consider using `ignoreDupResponses` and `requestDelay` attributes ([Documentation](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/support.jsf?tab=info)):

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider id="slider"
    rendered="#{bean.showReductionForm}"
    value="#{bean.reduction}" 
    showArrows="true"
    width="220">

    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="datatableId"
        ajaxSingle="true"
        actionListener="#{bean.appRed}"
        ignoreDupResponses="true"
        requestDelay="300"/> 

</rich:inputNumberSlider>
```